# how to set the CFO standard deviation in CFO models

Tags: gnuradio

I need some help with a simple thing. I am trying to simulate carrier frequency offset model for Bluetooth Low Energy standard in GNURadio (I am bit new to this). For this purpose, there is a CFO model already available in it details of which are available here https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/CFO_Model . I need to correctly parameterize the model with some values according to some of the knowns about the standard

- Channel Bandwidth  2MHz
- Frequency (f)      2.4GHz
- Maximum crystal Oscilator inaccuracy  (ppm)   20.8ppm   dictated by standard
- Maximum CFO bound (f*ppm/10^6)        49920Hz
- Sample rate ( R )                     4MHz
- Sample duration (1/R)                 0.00000025s
- CFO standard deviation (Hz per sample)

Can you please check if parameter values are correct. How can I determine the CFO standard deviation (Hz per sample) as described in the above link in this case?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!